# Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List

Tags: java, kotlin

Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List

Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List

Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List

Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.BaseVariantData.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List

Answer (score 0):

In your app build.gradle file update kotlin version

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
```

like this

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'

...

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}
```

more details refer [kotlin Targeting Android](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html)